# AJAX inserts jQuery script into results div

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

What I am trying to achieve is have the form appear if there was nothing submitted. So I add the form html to a variable and then echo the variable inside the html.

However ever since I implemented AJAX, inside the #results div. It also exports the jquery.js and my ajax script.

If I remove the PHP else code that displays the form, I won't see the form at all.

[image]

So how would someone make sure the js scripts aren't being inserted where they shouldn't be?

PHP:

```
if( isset($_POST["u_name"]) && isset($_POST["u_lastname"]) && isset($_POST["u_email"]) ){

    $servername = "";
    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO testTable (Name, Lastname, Email)

    VALUES ('".$_POST["u_name"]."','".$_POST["u_lastname"]."','".$_POST["u_email"]."')";


    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error."";
    }

    $conn->close();


}else {
    $final_content = '<form action="script.php" method="post" id="user_form">

    <input type="text" name="u_name" placeholder="Name" id="user_name"> <br>
    <input type="text" name="u_lastname" placeholder="Lastname" id="user_lastname"> <br>
    <input type="email" name="u_email" placeholder="Email" id="user_email"> <br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
    </form>';
}
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>


        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            //Set form variable
            var form = $("#user_form");

            form.submit(function(event){

                //Set data variables
                var user_name = $("#user_name").val();
                var user_lastname = $("#user_lastname").val();
                var user_email = $("#user_email").val();

                    //Check if values are set
                    if( ($.trim(user_name) != "") && ($.trim(user_lastname) != "") && ($.trim(user_email) != "") ){

                        $.post("script.php", {u_name: user_name, u_lastname: user_lastname, u_email: user_email}, function(data){

                            $("#results").html(data);   

                        });
                    }

                event.preventDefault();
            });

        });
        </script>

    </head>

    <body>





<?php echo $final_content ?>

<div id="results"></div>

    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an `exit();` right after `$conn->close();`, just above the `else`.

This will make sure that once you have output the results, you do not continue with the rest of the code (not included in your question) where you output the full HTML page with `script` tags and `<div id="results">` ...etc.

Apparently that display code is not all inside the `else` block, but also further down, *after* the `else` block.